# Criar uma função que retorna numero aleatório em C

Tags: c, random

Boa tarde, eu tenho um projeto em linguagem c para entregar, e já está quase tudo pronto, mas o professor disse q temos q usar uma função que retorna numero aleatório, mas a função aleatória eu é q tenho que criar, só que eu estou sem ideia é nem vejo como fazer, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Leo, o objetivo aqui é ensinar a pescar e não pescar para você. Tente construir algo com o que você já sabe. Conforme for encontrando problemas, pode pedir ajuda aqui, a comunidade ficará feliz em ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar usar uma função que gera números randômicos.

Por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
     int i;

     printf("Gerando 10 valores aleatorios:\n\n");

     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
           /* gerando valores aleatórios entre zero e 100 */
           printf("%d ", rand() % 100);
     }

     getch();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na plataforma Linux, não há suporte para o header conio.h.

Answer (score -1):

A própria linguagem C fornece uma função para gerar números "aleatórios" (pseudo aleatórios). Para tornar o número "mais aleatório", você pode utilizar o tempo para semear a função.

Cabeçalhos necessários:

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
```

Código:

```
srand (time(NULL));
rand();
```

Leia mais no [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/).